# SonarQube regex security hotspot

Tags: java, regex, sonarqube, java-11

We are using regular expression which supports for `MM/DD/YYYY` (or) `DD/MM/YYYY` (or) `M/D/YYYY`. The regular expression is `obj.matches(".*\\d+\\/\\d+\\/[0-9]{4}.*")`

But recently when twe introduced sonarqube in our build and it is failing because of this regex (**catastrophic backtracking regex**). Is there any other regex which can be used ?

we are using **java-11**.

Answer (score 1):

Any pattern that starts with indefinitely quantified patterns like `.*` or `.+` and then containing more subpatterns can slow down code execution with very large strings due to eventual backtracking.

You need to use a method that does not anchor the search at the start and end of the string, and this way you will eliminate `.*` at the start and end of the pattern:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+/\\d+/\\d{4}").matcher(obj);
if (m.find()) {
  // ....
}
```

Do not escape `/` chars, they are not special regex metacharacters.

The pattern above is the best you can shorten the pattern to, and you can safely mark the regex as *reviewed* and good to use.

Comment: You can improve the performance even more by using `\\d++` here, disabling backtracking for the digits too, as it is predictable that digits can not match the `/` character. Though, `\\d{1,2}` or `\\d\\d?` would be more appropriate anyway.